# Triggereing 1K android apps on some event - Suggestions

Tags: java, android

We have a strange requirement where we have to trigger 1k android apps for a digital wall having devices. We do not have WLAN/INTERNET connection.We want to run an animation in all the devices , synced together.For this we need a trigger to initiate android apps.

I was working with Sound frequency check, but not sure if it is feasible to trigger each and everyone without lag.

Please provide any other suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Turn the earth magnetic field upside down and register that using the electro-magnetic sensor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question and requires either original research or reference recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a time-based trigger. I expect that you have at least connection to a your mobile provider network which you can use to synchronize clocks. Once you do that, you can use any means of communication with the devices to notify them about the next time to run your animation at a given time.

For example, you could send a SMS message with the time to all devices containing the time when to trigger the animation. There will be a lag before all messages are delivered but if the trigger time is in future further than maximum lag, you will still achieve synchronization.

Or you can use another sensor, such as microphone, camera, maybe even Bluetooth. If you write your application to be triggered by a clap or flash, all devices may trigger at a reasonably similar time (especially if they were the same model with the same installed apps). It depends on how much precision you require. If e.g. sound is not precise enough, you can improve synchronization with time again - set the animation to run at the nearest second/ten seconds/... boundary after the trigger event.

All in all, it depends on your exact requirements (precision, ...) and you will probably need to do some experimenting. Internet connection would probably be the most precise trigger, though. Almost all Android devices have access to WiFi and setting up an access point is not difficult